# Using jQuery to find which row was clicked in a table

Tags: jquery, function, html-table, click, row

I've been following a guide on [expandable rows](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/#expandablerows) and now I'd like to know what row has been clicked in my table.

The table has this format:

```
Parent
--child
--child
Parent
etc.
```

When a child row is clicked, I'd like to know what text is in the cell (only the text, not the html or more information). How do I retrieve that data?

```
$(function() {
    $('tr[class^=child-]')
    .css("cursor","pointer")
    .attr("title","Click for more info")
    .click(function(){
        //Get row cell text (perhaps use $(this)?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply using `$(this).find('td:first').text()` if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I have two columns. $(this).text() gives the result: column1.text + column2.text. I do not want the text from both column. Ideas?

Comment: @Dennis Which column do you want it from?

Comment: Hey, that worked. Thank you very much! This language is too simple for me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).text()
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question that your title asks, finding the row clicked in the table:

```
$(document).on('click', 'table tr', function() {
    rn = this.rowIndex;
    alert('You clicked row: '+rn);
});
```

OR

```
$('table tr').click( function() {
    rn = this.rowIndex;
    alert('You clicked row: '+rn);
});
```